# how can i use aes-256 encrypt in postgrepsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tested this script in Postgresql:

```
select encode(encrypt('123456','F2388451B0954326','aes'),'BASE64');
```

But, this is AES128 encryption. How can I use aes-256 encryption in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Use of "encrypt" is clearly discouraged by the docs.  Why not use pg_sym_encrypt instead, which makes it pretty easy to select aes256?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **pgcrypto** extension, install it with:

```
create extension pgcrypto
```

now, after pgcrypto installed successfully, use **pgp_sym_encrypt** function

```
select encode(pgp_sym_encrypt('123456','F2388451B0954326','compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256'),'BASE64');
```

please note that first parameter '123456' is data, second parameter is password

hope that answer your question

Comment: i used that function before,but the result is not the same with i encrypt aes-256 in java code,while i change the function parameter key with 32bytes like 'F2388451B0954326F2388451B0954326',the function result is the same with java code result,so does the encrypt function work as aes-256 when i use 256bit key?

Comment: Thats related to how aes-256 encryption works, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42642/should-aes-always-give-the-same-output) for more information, but basicly as long as encrypted text (the result) can be decrypted in both java and posgresql with same password, that mean it is a valid encrypted text..